# What is the most effective way to block IP address in Application Layer?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ddos, iptables

I understand that most Routers/Firewalls are able to block IP tables in the network level. IPtables for instance is quite effective.

However, I want an application layer IP block.I have an HAproxy load balancer that load balances traffic to 4 backend apache/nginx web servers. I sometimes encounter scraping and GET request DDoS on my website. 
I want to be able to quickly(manually) block IP address on the application layer. How do I block an IP address, Apache Allow/Deny, .httaccess? Is there a more effective/easier way to block the IPs? What if I have a huge list to block? I would also appreciate a way of blocking specific. User Agents.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the mod_evasive module for Apache. It has capability to interact with IPtables if you need that, you can set Whitelist also.

Here are some documentation about it:
https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/apache-tips-and-tricks/modevasive-on-apache

Update:

For manually blocking or using a list.txt file, you can use the iptables tool and/or shell command that reads the list.txt file, something like this:

```
for i in `cat list.txt`; do iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s $i -j DROP; done
```

In this case the list.txt contains IP addresses per line.

For further info about iptables tool:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! But What if I want to manually block an IP address or a list.txt of ip addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this: [FailToBan](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

It scans logfiles from your apache and blocks ip's with malicious requests. However i don't have experience with this, it might be worth a try!

You can ban certain user-agents in your configuration and load an additional module called:  mod_authz_host(http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html). This might be a good solution. But attackers can easily change their user-agent. Thus maybe above solution might be more helpful.

Greets

Samuel

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought to use GeoIP modules? These are specifically designed to handle efficiently a large list of IPs at application level and allow to take decision about them (for instance allow, block, redirect, etc.).